# How to optimize an algorithm for a given multi-core architecture

Tags: multithreading, caching, optimization, multicore, cpu-architecture

I would like to know what techniques I should look up-to for optimizing a given  algorithm for a given architecture. How do I improve performance using better caching. How do I reduce cache coherency or what access patterns should I avoid in my algorithm/program so that cache coherency doesn't impact my performance?

I understand a few standard techniques for using the recently cached data in L1  but how would I use data in a shared cache(say L2) on a multi-core effectively thereby I avoid a main-memory access which is even more costlier?

Basically, I am interested in what data access patterns I should try to exploit or avoid for a better mapping to my given architecture. What data structure I could use, in what scenarios for what architectures(with different levels of private cache and shared cache) to improve performance. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What techniques I should look up-to for optimizing a given algorithm for a given architecture?**

Micro-architectures vary, so learn the details of your specific processor.  Intel provides good documentation in their [optimization guide](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html).  If you are using an Intel processor you'll want to read sections 8.3 and 8.6:

***8.3 OPTIMIZATION GUIDELINES***
This section summarizes optimization guidelines for tuning multithreaded applications. Five areas are listed (in order of importance):

- Thread synchronization
- Bus utilization
- Memory optimization
- Front end optimization
- Execution resource optimization

Practices associated with each area are listed in this section. Guidelines for each area are discussed in greater depth in sections that follow. Most of the coding recommendations improve performance scaling with processor cores; and scaling due to HT Technology. Techniques that apply to only one environment are noted.

***8.6 MEMORY OPTIMIZATION***

Efficient operation of caches is a critical aspect of memory optimization. Efficient operation of caches needs to address the following:

- Cache blocking
- Shared memory optimization
- Eliminating 64-KByte aliased data accesses
- Preventing excessive evictions in first-level cache

**What data access patterns I should try to exploit or avoid for a better mapping to my given architecture?**

***Exploit***

When caches are full and an access misses in the cache the cache must evict something to make room for the new data/code, what is evicted is usually based on an approximation of least-recently used (LRU).  If possible then your code should have strong [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference):

- Try to pack data that is used close in time in the algorithm such that it is close in space (address)
- Pack data tightly, don't use a 64-bit integer when a 32-bit integer will do, for example
- Sometimes the alignment of an "object" (related data) relative to a cache line matters. For example, if there is an array of objects each of 64-bytes and they are accessed randomly then aligning at a 64-byte boundary will improve cache efficiency by not bringing in data that is not used. If the object isn't aligned then every object touched brings in two cache lines, but only 64-bytes are needed, so 50% of data transferred isn't used (assumes cache lines are 64-bytes).
- As @PaulA.Clayton pointed out in the comments, pre-fetching data is very important, as it hides part or all of the memory latency. "*Also, exploiting stride-based hardware prefetching can be quite beneficial. (Software prefetching can also be useful in some cases.) Getting pointers early helps increase memory-level parallelism.*"
- In order to facilitate the hardware pre-fetcher and to increase the utilization of the data that is brought into the cache pay careful attention to how matrices and other large structures are stored and accessed... see [Wikipedia article on row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

**Avoid**

- Data that you don't use often shouldn't be close to data that you use frequently
- Avoid [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).  If two or more threads access the same cache line but are not sharing the same data within the cache line and at least one of them is a writer you have false sharing... there will be unnecessary burden and latency hit associated with [cache coherency protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence#Coherency_protocol).
- Try not to use new data until you are done with the older data

***Measure***

As Andrei Alexandrescu said [in this talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Writing-Quick-Code-in-Cpp-Quickly) - when it comes to performance tuning the only intuition that is right is "I should measure this."  Familiarize yourself with cache performance monitoring tools, for example:

- [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)
- [Cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html)

Comment: If the memory/cache interface supports critical chunk first, placing the first used data at the beginning of a cache line does not provide an advantage. Even without such, the advantage would be small. The goal is to use with temporal locality as much data in the cache line as possible, which part of the cache line generates the miss is less important. Also, exploiting stride-based hardware prefetching can be quite beneficial. (Software prefetching can also be useful in some cases.) Getting pointers early helps increase memory-level parallelism.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton I agree, I'll rephrase that.  The point I was trying to make (and failed) was that sometimes the alignment of an "object" (related data) relative to a cache line matters.  If there is an array of objects each of 64-bytes and they are accessed randomly then aligning at a 64-byte boundary will improve cache efficiency by not bringing in data that is not used.  If the object isn't aligned then every object touched brings in two cache lines, but only 64-bytes are needed, so 50% of data transferred isn't used.  Also, very good point about hardware prefetching, I'll add that as well.

Comment: One classic decision point for spatial locality is Structure of Arrays vs. Array of Structures. This can apply to jump tables for polymorphic classes; if one is accessing a given virtual method for many objects, grouping the method pointers by virtual method rather than by class can reduce cache misses (not really an option when using a language/compiler's implementation). Data packing can also include pointer compression even if it adds some computation such as a left shift. Hot/cold code/data separation is another classic, though hot data aggregation can cause false sharing. **Big** topic!

Comment: Thanks amdn and @Paul A. Clayton for your informative and detailed inputs! I feel that most of the techniques address L1 performance(please correct me if I am wrong). How would I use data in a shared cache on a multi-core effectively? Is the shared cache or a private lower level cache just to buffer the evicted L1 values and load them when required with a lower cost than a main memory reference? Do they have other impacts on performance of cache? Are there specific techniques available that concentrate on utilizing the shared cache data or reducing misses on L2?

Comment: @Shyam, you are welcome.  The following Intel document will address your question on techniques for shared caches, I'll update my answer later to summarize: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/software-techniques-for-shared-cache-multi-core-systems

Answer (score 0):

The key principle is locality: when you have the choice, process nearby data first (avoid sparse accesses), and perform data reuse as soon as possible (regroup successive passes over the same data).

For multithreaded programs, the principle is separate locality: ensure that the threads work on disjoint data sets (use distinct copies is necessary/possible).

Unless you have very good reasons to do so, stay away from the peculiarities of the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It should be mentioned that code is also cached in the same way as data. Small, dense code with a lot of inlining and few jumps/calls will put less strain on the L1C cache and, ultimately, L2, L3 and RAM where collisions with data fetches will occur.

If you are using hyperthreading there appears to be evidence to indicate that a lower optimization level (O1) on two hyperthreads in a core will overall get more work done than a single, highly optimized (O2 and higher) thread.